# exclude nulls in column SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

new to SSRS

I have table with column 1 is Department, and column 2 is The calculation

For example sum of the cost...

I have used the expression below to sum the cost

but I want to exclude the department that are null, but its no joy..

> =Sum(IIF(Fields!ReturnOrder.Value = "1" + IsNothing(Fields!Department.Value) = 1, Fields!Cost.Value, 0))

column 1 is still showing the null department. I do not wish to show this...

I just want to have a column 1 showing the department names, that does not show the null rows.. and column 2 sum of cost where return value = 1

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your expression work the way you have it, you need to change the plus to an AND for logical operations and leave the ISNOTHING as a Boolean (without the = 1):

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!ReturnOrder.Value = "1" AND NOT(IsNothing(Fields!Department.Value)), Fields!Cost.Value, 0))
```

I'm not sure what the ReturnOrder is for but left your condition in.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response...this has returned all 0, for the sum of cost...and the blank / null row for department has sill returned... please help

Comment: Sorry - after re-evaluating, there should be a NOT in front of the IsNothing because you had the `= false` (duh). I have updated the code.

Comment: This is calculating but the null row for the department is still showing..is there a setting on the table I can use report builder 3.0 to hide the null row. The row now shows as **blank for department and 0 for cost**  please help

Comment: For that issue, you'd need to use the ROW VISIBILTY. Select **Show or Hide Based on Expression** and use `=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Department.value), True, False)` to hide the NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to alter your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE [Department] IS NOT NULL;
```

You can also select the details row, click the Properties tab, and enter a formula in the "Hidden" property

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Department.value), True, False)
```

This says, "if department is null, hide this row, otherwise show it". The first method is better because less data is returned to your report. The second method requires that all rows are returned, and the report has to sort through which ones to show.

Select the detail row (click the three lines), select the Properties tab, and replace "False" with that formula:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response . this has made all the departments say true instead...and false for the null. I just want to show the names of the departments and not show the null department row. please help

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't go into a field, it goes into the "hidden" property for the details row: if department is null then "hidden" = true. I'll add an image to my answer...

Answer (score 0):

The expression you are looking for is

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!ReturnOrder.Value = "1" AND IsNothing(Fields!Department.Value) = False, Fields!Cost.Value, 0))
```

**Tip:** In case your value is decimal instead of 0 use Cdec(0) to avoid errors.

To avoid displaying null departments I would suggest filtering your SQL query.

You can also do it by filtering the tablix

```
Expression: IsNothing(Fields!Department.Value)
Type: Boolean
Operator: Equal =
Value: False
```

Doing so will hide Null departments and your expression can be simplified to

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!ReturnOrder.Value = "1", Fields!cost.Value, 0))
```

[image]

[image]